# Finding out since when the value stay unchanged in Table using pure SQL query without any procedure or function

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table like below about Stock information which updated daily without deleting former data.

```
Table Name : StockInfo
---------------------------------------------
Date    |   ProductName   |    Stock        |
---------------------------------------------
20, Jul |     Buds        |   0             |
---------------------------------------------
20, Jul |     Monitor     |   1             |
---------------------------------------------
19, Jul |     Buds        |   0             |
---------------------------------------------
18, Jul |     Monitor     |   0             |
---------------------------------------------
17, Jul |     Buds        |   1             |
---------------------------------------------
16, Jul |     Monitor     |   15            |
---------------------------------------------
15, Jul |     Buds        |   5             |
---------------------------------------------
14, Jul |     Buds        |   0             |
---------------------------------------------
```

-- Note that Monitor's data of 15, Jul is not exists because the Monitor is newly came out at 16, July.

Using table above, what I want to have is like below.
Assume that today is 20, July.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ProductName    |    IsSoldoutNow     |     SoldoutDate     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   Buds         |       TRUE          |      19, July       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  Monitor       |       FALSE         |        NULL         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to crop such value using pure SQL with good performance?
What I want to know is if specific product is soldout or not and if soldout, since when?
I'm planning `join` above table with other table like below,
And Will create Excel-like table on the web using Node. And querying must be fast due to rendered by scroll down, up.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| ProductName  |  Price  | IsSoldoutNow  | SoldoutDate |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I considered to process this within Javascript, but it will give bed effect on performances, and I should give up DB-side groupping and sorting.

How can I get such data?

Comment: I don't understand this 'Note that Monitor's data of 15, Jul is not exists because the Monitor is newly came out at 16, July.'  does this mean you want all products even if they didn't exist at the query run date - so if the query was run for 15th then monitor should be included in the result set . If so what should the result look like?(monitor,null,null?)

Comment: @P.Salmon, Nope, maybe I need to remove that notice. seems it confuse little bit. What I need is just latest stock status of each product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(Dt  date,   ProductName  varchar(20),    Stock int);
insert into t values
('2019-07-20',     'Buds'        ,   0) ,            
('2019-07-20',     'Monitor'     ,   1) ,            
('2019-07-19',     'Buds'        ,   0) ,            
('2019-07-18',     'Monitor'     ,   0) ,            
('2019-07-17',     'Buds'        ,   1) ,            
('2019-07-16',     'Monitor'     ,   15),            
('2019-07-15',     'Buds'        ,   5) ,            
('2019-07-14',     'Buds'        ,   0 );            

     select t.*,t1.dtlastinstock,firstsoldout,
            case when t.stock = 0 then 'true' else 'false' end as soldout,
            case when t.stock = 0 then firstsoldout else null end as soldoutdate
     from t 
     left join
     (
      select dt,productname,stock,dtlastinstock,
                (select dt from t t1 
                        where t1.dt > dtlastinstock and t1.productname = s.productname and stock = 0
                        order by dt limit 1) firstsoldout
      from
      (
      select   dt,productname,stock,
                    (select dt from t t1 
                        where t1.dt < '2019-07-20' and t1.productname = t.productname and stock > 0
                        order by dt desc limit 1) dtlastinstock
      from t
     where dt = 
     (select dt from t t1 
     where t1.dt <= '2019-07-20' and t1.productname = t.productname 
     order by dt desc limit 1) and
     stock = 0
     ) s
     ) t1 on t1.productname = t.productname
     where t.dt =
         (select dt from t t1 
     where t1.dt <= '2019-07-20' and t1.productname = t.productname 
     order by dt desc limit 1) ;
```

Where the inner query finds the last time and item was in stock and repositions to find the first sold out date after that if there is one. Both the inner an outer query search for the most recent entry for items based on date.

```
+------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| Dt         | ProductName | Stock | dtlastinstock | firstsoldout | soldout | soldoutdate |
+------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
| 2019-07-20 | Buds        |     0 | 2019-07-17    | 2019-07-19   | true    | 2019-07-19  |
| 2019-07-20 | Monitor     |     1 | NULL          | NULL         | false   | NULL        |
+------------+-------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your codes are best for this purpose, i need your query to combined with my sql